# Kimono Desktop's payload url and index fields missing

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, desktop, electron, kimono

With the Kimono Web, in the crawled payload there was always url and index field in every source URL JSON. But with the desktop, these fields are missing and my product was totally depends on it.

I'm browsing the source codes of Kimono Desktop but I couldn't manage to find that part.

The index field is explained in there ; https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203349674-Add-a-unique-index-to-each-result-object-

Can anyone help me with it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. I found this workaround for the missing url field with the desktop application http://mudd.com/blog/how-to-extract-vdp-data-from-your-website/

Also, in case you used the crawl scheduling feature with the Kimono web app, I found that if I edit my APIs and save them again it lets me choose a crawl frequency. I just discovered this so I'm crossing my fingers and waiting to see if it's really going to work.